# Re-render the component when the store state is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm stuck on this problem, I am using redux to solve this problem and divided question into 4 parts. What I am trying to achieve is dynamically map component props with the UI inside another component (also known as PropEditor Form). What I'm talking about, First see this it is not implemented yet it just a prototype that I want to implement.

[image: PropEditor Prototype]

I will also appreciate it if you provide me a better solution to solve this problem.

**My approach:**

I have a component named `Heading.js` which contains 2 props `hasFruit` a boolean type and a `fruitName` string type. It can be a component from any library but let's start with simple.

**src/components/Heading.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const Heading = (props) => {
    const { hasFruit, fruitName } = props;
    return <h1>Fruit name will show { hasFruit ? fruitName : 'Oh no!'}</h1>
};
```

***Part A: InputTypes***

I want to show this component props as a UI on the `PropEditor` component. So, I have to define the different UI components for the props. So, I have created 2 input type components.

**src/editor/components/types/Boolean.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const propTypes = {
    /** object for the boolean input type. */
    prop: PropTypes.shape({
        /** It will be the name of the prop.  */
        name: PropTypes.string,
        /** It will be the value of the prop.  */
        value: PropTypes.bool,
    }),
    /** onChange handler for the input */
    onChange: PropTypes.func
};

const defaultProps = {
    prop: {},
    onChange: (value) => value,
};



const Boolean = (props) => {

    const { prop, onChange } = props;

    return (
        <input
            id={prop.name}
            name={prop.name}
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.checked)}
            checked={prop.value}
        />
    );

};


Boolean.propTypes = propTypes;
Boolean.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Boolean;
```

**src/editor/components/types/Text.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {
    /** object for the text input type. */
    prop: PropTypes.shape({
        /** It will be the name of the prop.  */
        name: PropTypes.string,
        /** It will be the value of the prop.  */
        value: PropTypes.string
    }),
    /** onChange handler for the input */
    onChange: PropTypes.func
};

const defaultProps = {
    prop: {},
    onChange: (value) => value,
};



const Text = (props) => {

    const { prop, onChange } = props;

   const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        onChange(value);
    };


    return (
        <input
            id={prop.name}
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={prop.value}
        />
    );

};


Text.propTypes = propTypes;
Text.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Text;
```

Later we will import these components inside `PropForm` component which is the child of the `PropEditor` component. So we can map these types.

**src/editor/components/types/index.js**

```
import BooleanType from './Boolean';
import TextType from './Text';

export default {
    boolean: BooleanType,
    text: TextType,
};
```

***Part B: Redux***

The whole scenario, 2 actions will dispatch `SET_PROP` to set prop data on the store and `SET_PROP_VALUE` i.e. dispatch through `PropEditor` component when the input is changed and its update the value of the input.

**src/editor/actionTypes:**

```
// PropEditor Actions

// One single prop
export const SET_PROP = 'SET_PROP';

// One single prop value
export const SET_PROP_VALUE = 'SET_PROP_VALUE';
```

I have defined 2 action creators.

**src/editor/PropActions.js:**

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

// Prop related action creators
/**
 * @param prop {Object} - The prop object
 * @return {{type: {string}, data: {Object}}}
 */
export const setProp = (prop) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_PROP,
        data: prop
    };
};


// Prop value related actions
/**
 * @param prop {Object} - The prop object
 * @return {{type: {string}, data: {Object}}}
 */
export const setPropValue = (prop) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_PROP_VALUE,
        data: prop
    };
};
```

**src/editor/PropReducer.js:**

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export const propReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            // Prop Actions
            case (actionTypes.SET_PROP):
                const { data } = action;
                return { ...state, [data.name]: {...data} };

            // Prop Value Actions
            case (actionTypes.SET_PROP_VALUE):
                return { ...state, [action.data.name]: { ...state[action.data.name], value: action.data.value  } };
            default:
                return state;
        }
};
```

**src/editor/PropStore.js:**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { propReducer } from './PropReducer';

const REDUX_DEV_TOOL = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__();

export const store = createStore(propReducer, REDUX_DEV_TOOL);
```

Bootstrap our whole `App` with the `react-redux` provider on the DOM.

**src/index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './editor/PropStore';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

***Part C: Main part***

How to map component `Heading.js` props with a UI on the `PropEditor` component?

For this user has to wrap its component with a higher-order component and inside that `HOC` user has to call some functions which will behind the scenes help us to dynamically populate the store. I have created some functions like `boolean` and `text` which will dispatch an action named `SET_PROP` to populate the store state.

**src/editor/index.js**

```
import { store } from './PropStore';
import { setProp } from './PropActions';

/**
 * @param name {string} - The name of the prop
 * @param options {Object} - The prop with some additional properties
 * @return {*} - Returns the associated value of the prop
 */
const prop = (name, options)  => {
    const defaultValue = options.value;
    // Create an object and merge with additional properties like `defaultValue`
    const prop = {
        ...options,
        name,
        defaultValue,
    };
    store.dispatch(setProp(prop));
    return defaultValue;
};

/**
 * @param name {string} - The name of the prop
 * @param value {boolean} - The value of the prop
 * @return {boolean} - Returns the value of the prop
 */
export const boolean = (name, value) => {
    // Returns the value of the prop
    return prop(name, { type: 'boolean', value });
};

/**
 * @param name {string} - The name of the prop
 * @param value {string} - The value of the prop
 * @return {text} - Returns the value of the prop
 */
export const text = (name, value) => {
    // Returns the value of the prop
    return prop(name, { type: 'text', value });
};
```

***Render the `HOC` component and `PropEditor` on the DOM:***

**src/blocks.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { boolean, text } from './editor';
import { Heading } from './components/Heading';


// WithHeading Block
export const WithHeading = () => {
    const boolVal = boolean('hasFruit', true);
    const textVal = text('fruitName', 'Apple');
    return (<Heading hasFruit={boolVal} fruitName={textVal}/>);
};
```

This is our main `App` component.

**src/App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { PropEditor } from './editor/components/PropEditor';
import { WithHeading } from './blocks';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {/* PropEditor */}
            <PropEditor />
            {/* Blocks */}
            <WithHeading/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

***Part D: Final Part `PropEditor` component***

`PropEditor` will dispatch an action when any input is changed but remember all our `props` are converted into an array of objects for rendering the UI which will be passed inside the `PropForm` component.

**src/editor/components/PropEditor.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { PropForm } from './PropForm';
import { setPropValue } from '../PropActions';

export const PropEditor = () => {

    // Alternative to connect’s mapStateToProps
    const props = useSelector(state => {
        return state;
    });

    // Alternative to connect’s mapDispatchToProps
    // By default, the return value of `useDispatch` is the standard Dispatch type defined by the
    // Redux core types, so no declarations are needed.
    const dispatch = useDispatch();



    const handleChange = (dataFromChild) => {
        dispatch(setPropValue(dataFromChild));

    };

    // Convert objects into array of objects
    const propsArray = Object.keys(props).map(key => {
        return props[key];
    });


    return (
        <div>
            {/* Editor */}
            <div style={styles.editor}>
                <div style={styles.container}>
                    { propsArray.length === 0
                      ? <h1 style={styles.noProps}>No Props</h1>
                      : <PropForm props={propsArray} onFieldChange={handleChange} />
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**src/editor/components/PropForm.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TypeMap from './types';

const propTypes = {
    props: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    onFieldChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

// InvalidType component
const InvalidType = () => (<span>Invalid Type</span>);

export const PropForm = (properties) => {

    /**
     * @param name {string} - Name of the prop
     * @param type {string} - InputType of the prop
     * @return {Function} - Returns a function
     */
    const makeChangeHandler = (name, type) => {
        const { onFieldChange } = properties;
        return (value = '') => {
            // `change` will be an object and value will be from the onChange
            const change = {name, type, value};
            onFieldChange(change);
        };
    };
    // Take props from the component properties
    const { props } = properties;

    return (
        <form>
            {
                props.map(prop => {
                    const changeHandler = makeChangeHandler(prop.name, prop.type);
                    // Returns a component based on the `type`
                    // if the `type` is boolean then
                    // return Boolean() component
                    let InputType = TypeMap[prop.type] || InvalidType;
                    return (
                        <div style={{marginBottom: '16px'}} key={prop.name}>
                             <label htmlFor={prop.name}>{`${prop.name}`}</label>
                             <InputType prop={prop} onChange={changeHandler}/>
                        </div>
                      );
                })
            }
        </form>
    );
};

PropForm.propTypes = propTypes;
```

After all this explanation my code is working perfectly.

The problem is re-rendering of the `Heading` component is not happening when `SET_PROP_VALUE` action is dispatched on the input change inside the `PropEditor` component.

[image: Redux Store Debugging]

The store is changed perfectly as you can see with the [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) extension but the re-render of the component `Heading` is not happening.

I think because inside my `HOC` `text()` and `boolean()` functions are not returning an updated value.

**Is there a way to solve this problem?**

Please don't mention this I have to connect my `WithHeading` component with the `react-redux`. I know this but Is there a way the functions like `boolean('hasFruit', true)` and `text('fruitName', 'Apple')` returns the latest value when the store state is updated?

Codesandbox: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-f4ff9)

Repository: [Repository](https://github.com/Ah-debug/prop-editor-redux)

Comment: You can communicate between the components if it is a `parent-child` relation or `child-parent` relation direct communication between 2 separate components is not possible in `reactjs`. You have to come with another pattern use the event emitter pattern to emit the event on `PropManager` class and listen inside the `PropEditor` it is a complex process. Instead, use redux to solve this problem create a prop store, and dispatch an action to manipulate the prop value. https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: @TimmyMucks Can you provide me an example on the redux or event-emitter-pattern?

Comment: @TimmyMucks I edit the question and now using `redux` please read the question again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I've created 4 demos, each demo is an extended version of the previous one :

**1)** Connect the sore and update component via mapStateToProps

**2)** By Using the `useSelector`

```
 const boolVal = useSelector(state => state.hasFruit ? state.hasFruit.value : false );
```

**3)** Paasing the dynamic name to useSelector

```
const booleanVal = useSelector(state => booleanSelector(state, "hasFruit"));
```

**4)** Created a custom hook, so that you can get the updated value bu just passing the name

```
const booleanVal = useGetValueFromStore("hasFruit");
```

---

> **The problem is re-rendering of the Heading component is not happening**

**Reason :**

Yes because it's not connected to the store, how does it know that there are some changes going on the `store`, you need to call `connect` to make a connection with the store and be up to date with changes.

Here is the updated code of the `blocks.js` :

```
// WithHeading Block
const WithHeading = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    boolean("hasFruit", true); // <--- Setting initial value
    text("fruitName", "Apple"); // <--- Setting initial value
  }, []); // <----- get called only on mount

  return <Heading hasFruit={props.boolVal} fruitName={props.textVal} />;

};

// to get updated state values inside the component as props
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    boolVal: state.hasFruit ? state.hasFruit.value : false,
    textVal: state.fruitName ? state.fruitName.value : ""
  };
};

// to make connection with store
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WithHeading);
```

**1) WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit #SO-redux-connect]

---

Another approach is you can use `useSelector` :

```
// WithHeading Block
const WithHeading = props => {
  // console.log(props);
  const boolVal = useSelector(state =>
    state.hasFruit ? state.hasFruit.value : false
  );
  const textVal = useSelector(state =>
    state.fruitName ? state.fruitName.value : ""
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    boolean("hasFruit", true);
    text("fruitName", "Apple");
  }, []);

  return <Heading hasFruit={boolVal} fruitName={textVal} />;
};

export default WithHeading;
```

**2) WORKING DEMO :**

### [image: Edit #SO-redux-connect2]

You can also put the selector in separate file,so that you can use it whenever you want

```
const WithHeading = props => {
  // you can pass the input names here, and get value of it
  const booleanVal = useSelector(state => booleanSelector(state, "hasFruit"));
  const textVal = useSelector(state => textValSelector(state, "fruitName"));

  useEffect(() => {
    boolean("hasFruit", true);
    text("fruitName", "Apple");
  }, []);

  return <Heading hasFruit={booleanVal} fruitName={textVal} />;
};
```

**3) WORKING DEMO :**

### [image: Edit #SO-redux-connect3]

Custom Hook with use of `useSelector` :

```
// a function that will return updated value of given name
const useGetValueFromStore = name => {
  const value = useSelector(state => (state[name] ? state[name].value : ""));
  return value;
};

// WithHeading Block
const WithHeading = props => {

  //------- all you need is just to pass the name --------
  const booleanVal = useGetValueFromStore("hasFruit");
  const textVal = useGetValueFromStore("fruitName");

  useEffect(() => {
    boolean("hasFruit", true);
    text("fruitName", "Apple");
  }, []);

  return <Heading hasFruit={booleanVal} fruitName={textVal} />;
};

export default WithHeading;
```

**4) WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-redux-connect4]

Comment: I know this but Is there a way the functions like `boolean('hasFruit', true)` and `text('fruitName', 'Apple')` returns the latest value when the store state is updated?

Comment: @VenNilson,  `Is there a way the functions like boolean('hasFruit', true) and text('fruitName', 'Apple')` , I've updated the answer and I think the last demo will provide the answer to you question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Create the custom hook is a nice idea and I noted this one.

Comment: @VenNilson, glad to know, it helped, :)

Comment: of course I will but StackOverflow is saying you can award your bounty after 24hrs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle state in React, and many of those choices are based on complexity and requirements. As mentioned in the comments, [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) is a powerful option. [Mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree) is a remarkable piece of technology, to name two.

React itself does have capacity to disseminate and respond to these changes without external libs. You might consider using the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) -

```
./src/contexts/Store

import React, {
  useContext,
  useState,
  useMemo,
  createContext,
  useEffect,
} from 'react';


const StoreContext = createContext(null);

const StoreProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, setLocalState] = useState({});

  function set(objToMerge) {
    setLocalState({ ...state, ...objToMerge });
  }

  function get(k) {
    return state[k];
  }

  function getAll(){
    return state;
  }

  const api = useMemo(() => {get, set, getAll}, []);
  return <StoreContext.Provider value={api} {...props}></StoreContext.Provider>;
};

function useStoreContext(): StoreProviderApi {
  const api = useContext(StoreContext);
  if (api === null) {
    throw new Error(
      'Component must be wrapped in Provider in order to access API',
    );
  }
  return api;
}

export { StoreProvider, useStoreContext };
```

to use, you do need a Parent level component -

```
import {StoreProvider} from './contexts/Store';

...
    <StoreProvider>
      <PropEditor/>
      <WithHeading/>
    </StoreProvider>
...
```

Then, within the component itself, you can access the latest state -

```
import {useStoreContext} from './contexts/Store';

export const Heading = (props) => {
    const store = useStoreContext();

    const { hasFruit, fruitName } = store.getAll();
    return <h1>Fruit name will show { hasFruit ? fruitName : 'Oh no!'}</h1>
};
```

This has the benefit of not needing to pass tons of props around, and it will auto-render on change.

The downside, however, is that it **will** re-render on change. That is, there are no mechanisms for selectively re-rendering only the components with changed props. Many projects have multiple contexts to alleviate this.

If your store props need to be used throughout the app, then Redux ([with the toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)) is a good option, because it is a store  outside of React, and it handles broadcasting only the prop changes to the subscribing components for those props, rather than re-rendering all of the subscribers (which is what the Context API does).

At that point, it becomes a question of architecture and what is needed for your application requirements.

Comment: I updated the question Now it is easy to answer the problem.